# Detecting drag and drop with Modernizr (not file drag and drop)

Tags: javascript, html, browser, drag-and-drop

I've spent a fair while looking for the answer to this question and either found answers that are out of date or answers that relate to file drag and drop.

I just want to check if a user's browser supports HTML5 drag and drop. At the moment the line...

```
if (!Modernizr.draganddrop) {
   // non-HTML5 alternative drag and drop code here
}
```

...returns true for any IE version I emulate. Why does Modernizr think that IE doesn't support drag and drop at all? I read that IE9 onward does...

Should I be checking the browser version instead?

Any help, much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use javascript rather than Modernizr:

```
function dragAndDropSupported () {
    return 'draggable' in document.createElement('span');
}
```

Check to see if dragAndDropSupported() === true

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Just a question: This looks like it creates a rogue span somewhere on the page; Do I need to then remove it?

Comment: This doesn't work in some cases, for example iOS Safari.

Comment: (Sorry, just getting back to this reply for whatever reason) The createElement is usually stored in a variable and appended to the DOM. In this case, it isn't stored, so it is just a temporary reference, so no need to delete anything.